# How to use DbSet.Find() with an entity that has an abstract class as key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an abstract `TaxNumber` type that is implemented by two types:
`CPF` and `CNPJ`.

`TaxNumber` is used as a primary key in the `Person` base model, which is also an abstract type and implemented by two types: `PhysicalPerson` and `LegalPerson`.

Knowing that:

When `Person` is `PhysicalPerson`, `TaxNumber` is `CPF`.

When `Person` is `LegalPerson`, `TaxNumber` is `CNPJ`.

The problem is when I run `DbContext.Persons.Find(CPF)` or `DbContext.Persons.Find(CNPJ)`.
The following exception is raised:

> **System.ArgumentException:** 'The key value at position 0 of the call to'
>   DbSet  .Find 'was of type' CPF ', which does not match the
>   property type' TaxNumber '.

Apparently, the value passed to `Find()` must be exactly of type `TaxNumber`, but `TaxNumber` is an abstract type and cannot be instantiated, how to use `Find()` in this scenario?

For better viewing:

```
public abstract Person 
{
    [Key]
    public TaxNumber TaxNumber { get; set; }
}

public abstract LegalPerson : Person
{
}

public abstract PhysicalPerson : Person
{
}
```

With the following configuration defined:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LegalPerson>()
    .Property(v => v.TaxNumber)
    .HasConversion(
        v => v.Unformatted,
        v => v == null ? null : new CNPJ(v));

modelBuilder.Entity<PhysicalPerson>()
    .Property(v => v.TaxNumber)
    .HasConversion(
        v => v.Unformatted,
        v => v == null ? null : new CPF(v));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the values as the base type:

```cs
DbContext.Persons.Find((TaxNumber)CPF)
DbContext.Persons.Find((TaxNumber)CNPJ)
```

**UPDATE:**

Or try declaring the values as the base type:

```cs
TaxNumber key = CPF;
DbContext.Persons.Find(key);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Try using a primitive type as the key instead.

> EF Core supports using properties of any primitive type as the primary key, including `string`, `Guid`, `byte[]` and others

Reference: [Key types and values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys#key-types-and-values)

Comment: @Joao Pedro I made another suggestion in the answer

Comment: Not even the exception message is changed.

Comment: Changing the key type will be a lot of work, I prefer to continue using `DbContext.Persons.SingleOrDefault(person => person.TaxNumber == CPF)`, which is not as clean or efficient as `Find()`, but it works.